# How to update a Visual Studio Databaseproject automatically

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

is it possible to update a databaseproject automatically? For example on a TFS build server?

I had a big database and just start with the databaseprojects. So currently our database is primary not updated by a databaseproject and thats the reason why i must update my project alot to get it sync with the database. Currently i use a preconfigured schemacompare of the datatools. But the update of the project must be done by hand :(

Is there any way to do that automatically?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you should probably look into creating a **.cmd** script that calls [SqlPackage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080.aspx). The operation you are interested in is `Extract`. You should be able to update your **.dacpac** file with the current DB schema using this.

Comment: And what might the problem be with my answer?

Comment: Hello srutzky, can i modify the Extract method or results? 
My problem ist that i have a very big database and i need not every objects from the database in my project (for example view, credentials and more). So its necessary for me to filte or reduce the delta between my databse and the databaseproject. Thats the reason why i use the schemacomparetool, because its possible to exlude objecttypes (like views, indices) from the he compare and following update of the project.

Comment: @user1481065 I do not think it is possible to filter those out. At least I don't see a way to do that.